# CURL / Ruby Alternative in Python to fetch data from API

Tags: python, ruby, api, curl, urllib2

I want to get data from an API using Python. The API documentation give examples in CURL and Ruby. I would be very happy if you can post code snippets on how to do the following things with Python.

To get authentication token:

Curl example:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"username\" : \"user@sample.com\", \"password\":\"sample\"}" http://api.sample.com/authenticate
```

Ruby example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

class AuthorizationClient
  attr_accessor :base_url

  def initialize(base_url)
    @base_url = base_url
  end

  def authenticate(username,password)
    login_data = { 'username' => username, 'password' => password}.to_json
    begin
      JSON.parse(RestClient.post "#{@base_url}/authenticate", login_data, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)['output']
    rescue Exception => e
      JSON.pretty_generate JSON.parse e.http_body
    end
  end
end

client = AuthorizationClient.new('http://api.sample.com/authenticate')
puts client.authenticate('user@sample.com','sample')
```

After authentication, to get data:

CURL example:

```
curl http://api.sample.com/data/day/2011-02-10/authToken/80afa08-1254-46ee-9545-afasfa4565
```

And Ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

class ReportingClient
  attr_accessor :auth_token, :base_url

  def initialize(base_url)
    @base_url = base_url
  end

  def authenticate(username,password)
    login_data = { 'username' => username, 'password' => password}.to_json

    response = RestClient.post "#{@base_url}/authenticate", login_data, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
    @auth_token = JSON.parse(response)['output']
  end

  def get_report(start_date, end_date)
    response = RestClient.get "#{@base_url}/data/day/#{day}/authToken/#{auth_token}"
    JSON.parse(response)
  end

end

client = ReportingClient.new('http://api.sample.com:20960')
client.authenticate('user@sample.com','sample')

results = client.get_report('2011-02-10')

puts JSON.pretty_generate(results)
```

Thank you..

PS: I am aware of pycurl. But I am not sure if I really need it. I am happy with using Python native libraries. Pycurl might be over-kill for my needs.

I am new to Python and I couldn't find the right solution after reading 'urllib2' documentation and trying examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a port but it looks like you are sending a POST and then obtaining the authorization token and then sending a GET request using this.
This is based on what I understood.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import simplejson
import datetime

authURL = "http://api.sample.com/authenticate"
values = {"username" : "user@sample.com",
          "password" : "sample"}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)

req = urllib2.Request(authURL, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

authToken = simplejson.load(response)["output"]

day = str(datetime.date.today())
dataURL = "http://api.sample.com/data/day/" + day + "/authToken/" + authToken

print simplejson.load(urllib2.urlopen(dataURL))
```

Comment: Thank you aNish for the answer. In fact, your answer is also more or less the same thing I came up with. Later I figured out it's not the code but the server with problem : ) I am getting HTTP 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

Which part exactly did you not understand after reading the urllib2 documentation?
I do not know my Ruby, but from the looks of it just involves sending GET request and POST requests in json format and parsing the responses. This is quite trivial with simplejson and urllib2.